# Javascript audio stream over Websocket to C# server

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to stream audio form web client to c# server over Websocket but i received the same bytes every time  .

client javascript code

```js
function audioplayer(){
    var stream;
    var bufferSize = 1024 * 16;
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    var processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
    processor.connect(audioContext.destination);
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: false,
        audio: true
      }).then( streamObj => {
        stream = streamObj;
        input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        input.connect(processor);
        processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
          microphoneProcess(e); 
        };
      });


//var obj = { command:"mic" , audio : btoa(new Blob(recording)) };
//ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
function microphoneProcess(e) {
    const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // get only one audio channel
    const left16 = convertFloat32ToInt16(left); // skip if you don't need this
    var obj = { command:"mic" , audio : btoa(left16) }
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj)) // send to server via web socket
}
function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
    let l = buffer.length;
    const buf = new Int16Array(l / 3);

    while (l--) {
      if (l % 3 === 0) {
        buf[l / 3] = buffer[l] * 0xFFFF;
      }
    }
    return buf.buffer;
}
```

c# server

```cs
if (data == null) return;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data)) {
    try {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(ms);
        player.Stream = ms;
        player.Play();
    } catch {
    }
}
DataRecv.Text = data.Length.ToString();
```

server give me error
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The wave header is corrupt.'

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the position then play it,

```cs
if (data == null) return;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data)) {
    try {
        ms.Position = 0;
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(ms);
        player.Stream = ms;
        player.Play();
    } catch {}

}
DataRecv.Text = data.Length.ToString();
```